# Debugging JS for a bot

Tags: node.js, discord, bots

I'm starting to code on JS with Visual Studio Code. I'm a total beginner, and here is my problem. What did I do wrong?

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client;

Client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot opérationnel");
});   

Client.login("MyTokenBot");
```

And I get this message on debug console :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Client is not defined
> No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
> Process exited with code 1

Thanks for your help

Comment: Make sure to add the parens to the end when you invoke a new instance of a class: `const client = new Discord.Client()`

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Please take a look at my answer, let me know if it helped - if so, please accept as correct answer - cheers !

Answer (score 1):

`Client` is not defined because you defined `client` (small c).
So this should work :

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

// const client = new Discord.Client;
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("bot opérationnel");
});   

client.login("MyTokenBot");
```

Also pretty sure if you create a new instance of a class you need to call the method as well, so instead of `new Discord.Client`, use `new Discord.Client()`

Comment: Oh no, we have almost duplicate answers. I'll delete mine, since you answered 3 seconds earlier

Comment: I guess we hit "Add Answer" almost simultaneously :D

Comment: Almost, your request finished 3 seconds earlier. I'll delete my answer